# null id Orchard repository creation Id identity on

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I use Orchard to create a new entry with this code

```
_repository.Create(new GMapZonePartRecord {
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                Commune = model.Commune,
                Quarter = model.Quarter,
                Price = model.Price,
                StartZoom = model.StartZoom,
                StopZoom = model.StopZoom,
                Color = model.Color,
                GMapPartRecord = partRecord
            });
```

where _repository is IRepository.
My code were working a long time ago and now I get an exception
My column id is identity on and in migration.cs:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GMapZonePartRecord",
            table => table
                .Column<int>("Id", col => col.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                .Column<string>("Name")
                .Column<string>("Description")
                .Column<string>("Color")
                .Column<int>("GMapPartRecord_Id"));
```

Here is the detail of error:

null id in JooWeb.GMap.Models.GMapZonePartRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.

Détails de l'exception: NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in JooWeb.GMap.Models.GMapZonePartRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Erreur source:

Ligne 159 :            }
Ligne 160 :
Ligne 161 :            return criteria
Ligne 162 :                .List()
Ligne 163 :                .Select(x => ContentManager.Get(x.ContentItemRecord.Id, _versionOptions != null && _versionOptions.IsDraftRequired ? _versionOptions : VersionOptions.VersionRecord(x.Id)))

Fichier source : c:\Users\JLA\Google Drive\Jooweb\Projects\Orchard.Source.1.7\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs    Ligne : 161

Trace de la pile:

```
[AssertionFailure: null id in JooWeb.GMap.Models.GMapZonePartRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)]
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.CheckId(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, EntityMode entityMode) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.cs:111
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.GetValues(Object entity, EntityEntry entry, EntityMode entityMode, Boolean mightBeDirty, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.cs:81
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.cs:36
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEntities(FlushEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:161
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:60
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.cs:30
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1182
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1959
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:265
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:276
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.Slice(Int32 skip, Int32 count) in c:\Users\JLA\Google Drive\Jooweb\Projects\Orchard.Source.1.7\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs:161
   Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentQuery`1.Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentQuery<T>.List() in c:\Users\JLA\Google Drive\Jooweb\Projects\Orchard.Source.1.7\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs:262
   Orchard.Widgets.Filters.WidgetFilter.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) +4348
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Users\JLA\Google Drive\Jooweb\Projects\Orchard.Source.1.7\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9676252
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Thanks for any help, I really don't know where to search.

EDIT:
After added source of Nhibernate 3.3.X, I found that the check that failed is not null value of ContentItemRecord.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug I download NHibernate source from https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/3.3.x
and discover that the null value were not id like the error message let us thinking but ContentItemRecord.

So I just add new value on this:

```
_repository.Create(new GMapZonePartRecord
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                Commune = model.Commune,
                Quarter = model.Quarter,
                Price = model.Price,
                StartZoom = model.StartZoom,
                StopZoom = model.StopZoom,
                Color = model.Color,
                GMapPartRecord = partRecord,
                ContentItemRecord = new ContentItemRecord()
            });
```

Now all is ok :)

Comment: Except that now you're probably creating content item records that don't have a type or parts. I'm not sure this won't come back to bite you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you say. A contentItemRecord is not a simple record to keep versionning of the record ? There is a link with the part that I don't need in my case ?

Comment: No, content item records represent content items.

Answer (score 2):

You should never, ever use `Repository<TRecord>` to create part records (and you should almost never use `Repository<TRecord>`, period). With your code, you've created orphan part records that do not correspond to a content item. Instead, use the APIs on `ContentManager` and it will take care of creating all the associated records for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it's exatly what I want. I only have GmapZonePartRecord and not GmapZonePart as ContentPart. I just want to use the repo to insert datas in DB.

Comment: Why is it called GmapZonePartRecord and not GmapZoneRecord then?

Comment: Euuh ... I think I should rename it like that :)